# JMSSerializer deserializing collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I have a problem with deserializing serialized collection of doctrine collections. Couldn't  find docs about that and any topics and I'm new with JMSSerializer. When I try deserialize with:

```
$collection = $serializer->deserialize($jsonData,'Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection','json');
```

$collection is empty

When I set to null instead of class name I have assoc array on result. Is there an elegant way to deserialize that json?

EDIT:
Sorry. Here is serialized collection:

```
[{"id":88,"name":"Poland","created_at":"2012-09-28T11:59:06+0000"},{"id":90,"name":"Great Britain","created_at":"2012-09-28T11:59:06+0000"}]
```

Comment: can you paste the json of the serialized `ArrayCollection` to the question?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Hah! Found what I done wrong :) I gave to deserialize method wrong type. Should be:

```
$serializer->deserialize($jsonData, 'ArrayCollection<EntityName>', 'json');
```

and it gave me beatiful array of entities.

Comment: Where did you find this solution?

Comment: by experiment only. No docs found unfortunately but looks like deserialize method can take as type argument same strings as defined for example here: [types](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/reference/annotations#type)

Comment: just what I was looking for. thanks for finding the solution!

Comment: Sorry to bring alive an old question, however I was wondering if this is done inside the controller or the view? 2 years on and the docs are still somewhat lacking.

Comment: You saved me  a lot of work this solution works perfectly thanks

Comment: I'm glad it is still helpful :)